# Is `this` pointer assignable in c++?

Tags: c++, this-pointer

when I try to assign a pointer to `this` pointer, My IDE(clion) said `Expression is not assignable`. So, Is `this` pointer assignable in c++ ? Is it a rvalue?

Comment: Why are you trying to assign to `this`? Note that `*this` is assignable; for example, in copy-and-swap idiom, `swap(*this, other)`, causing `*this` to be assigned to a temporary and a temporary to be a new `*this`. `this` remains the same, which is what is not assignable, and you wouldn't really want it to be anyway.

Comment: *when I try to assign a pointer to this pointer* Why would you do that?  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Back in the olden days, you could assign a value to `this` inside a constructor. That was a hack to provide a way of allocating objects on the free store. Then `operator new` was invented, and assigning to `this` was banned.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `this` is an rvalue. Specifically, it's a prvalue:

> The keyword `this` is a [prvalue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) [expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions) whose value is the address of the implicit object parameter (object on which the non-static member function is being called).

*(From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this)*

Hence, `this` is not assignable.